# windows mobile Technologies

Tags: c#

I want to do a sample application to send/receive SMS using mobile 5. Can any one give me suggestions for doing this or pls give any links for geting help
is there any option to do it using MS Visual studio 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sms.dll library to manipulate SMS in Windows mobile

Check the following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446545.aspx